# Generate SEF urls in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF1 you were able to create a SEF urkl by doing the following

```
 <a href="<?php $this->url(array('controller'=>'MyCOntroller', 
 'action'=>'MyActions'));?>">My link</a>
```

how do we do that in ZF2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve similar results also in Zend Framework 2 with something like following:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(
    'route-name', 
    array('controller'=>'MyCOntroller',  'action'=>'MyActions')
); ?>">My link</a>
```

Check the [reference about routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html) and the docs about the [URL view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#url-helper) and the [Controller URL Plugin Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-url-plugin)